# JQuery problem with .toggle function

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<div class="showcase">
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
</div>

<div class="showcase" style="display: none;">
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
</div>

<div class="showcase" style="display: none;">
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
       <a href="#"><img src="img/uploads/testchair.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.click').click(function() {
       $('.showcase').fadeOut('fast'); 
       $('.showcase').next('.showcase').show('fast');
    });
});
```

that is how my code is right now the only problem is when I press the div... the next 2 showcases are showing up I want to just the next showcase en when it is clicked again the next showcase div, how can I do this?  :)

Comment: Where is the element with `class='click'`?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: [`http://jsfiddle.net/MDEE2/1/`](http://jsfiddle.net/MDEE2/1/)

Basically, I added a variable to track which of the showcases that are currently being viewed, and then I just took the *next* one and made it pop-up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.click').click(function() {
        var active_show = $('.showcase:visible');
        active_show.fadeOut('fast');
        active_show.next('.showcase').show('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the `$('.showcase')` selector is applying to all the 'showcase' 'div' elements on the page. Is it possible for you to work out which 'div' has been clicked within the `$('.click').click` function?.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".showcase")` selects all elements with the class `showcase`. From your code it's hard to tell precisely what you want, but here's some code that will hide the first visible `.showcase` and show the next one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click').click(function() {
     $('.showcase:visible').eq(0).fadeOut('fast').next('.showcase').show('fast');
  });
});
```

References:
[**:visible**](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)
[**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) - or [**.first()**](http://api.jquery.com/first/) - or [**.filter(":first")**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

But if all the `.showcases` are invisible you want to just show the first one. So the whole code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click').click(function() {
   if ($('.showcase:visible').length > 0)
     $('.showcase:visible').eq(0).fadeOut('fast').next('.showcase').show('fast');
   else
     $('.showcase').eq(0).show('fast');
  });
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/WMHXb/)

And finally, you can probably [**clean it up to**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/VKTw7/):

```
$(function() {
    $('.click').click(function() {
        var $visible  = $('.showcase:visible'),
            $showcase = $('.showcase');
        if ($visible.length > 0)
            $visible.fadeOut('fast').next('.showcase').show('fast');
        else
            $showcase.eq(0).show('fast');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, $('.click') is not going to work, because there is no element in your HTML with that class. I think this is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showcase').click(function() {
       $(this).fadeOut('fast'); 
       $(this).next('.showcase').show('fast');
    });
});
```